# what is $x$ in $f=kx$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, displacement

hey I keep getting confused with this formula since different places get $\ x $ in different ways and I want to be sure im doing it the right way.

so i have a spring with a constant $\ 1300$ N/m,  length of $\ 110$ mm  and i want to compress it by $\ 4$ cm.

do i get $\ x $ by misusing the free length by what im compressing it by $\ 0.11 - 0.04 $ or is it just $\ 0.04 $

sorry for the really noob question but i just want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $x$ in $\vec{F}=-k\vec{x}$   is the net compression/ elongation of the spring.

Compression/Elongation: |natural length - current length| i.e. $\Delta x$

The '$-$' sign indicates that the force will be outward for compression and inward for elongation.

In your example, as the spring is compressed by $4 cm $ we have $x=4cm$.

Comment: awesome thank you so much. nice to know i was doing it right

Answer (score 0):

Hooke's law states that force is directly propotional to the compression or elongation. F=kx. Here

F=force that you apply to elongate the spring,

k= spring constant,

x= x is the elongation or compression caused due to my force. 
Here due to your force elongatioan caused is my 0.04 hence x= o.o4mm

Answer (score 0):

x is displacement.
The equation is a result of hooke's law.